# javax.inject @Inject not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, javax.inject

I am trying to understand how javax.inject gonna work, but it seems not working as expected.

```
package demo333;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

public class Demo2452 {

    @Inject private @Named("AA1") AA aa;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo2452().m2();
    }

    private void m2() {
        System.out.println(aa.hello());
    }

}


interface AA{
    String hello();
}

@Named("AA1")
class AA1 implements AA{

    @Override
    public String hello() {
        return "helllllooooo";
    }

}
```

I am getting NullPointerException as below stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   demo333.Demo2452.m2(Demo2452.java:15)     at
>   demo333.Demo2452.main(Demo2452.java:11)

Could anyone please tell me what went wrong in above code?

Comment: You must not call `new` yourself for objects for which injection should happen. For spring create a context, and ask it for an instance of this object class.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i didnt used new , please check my code

Comment: anyone can please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @gnat really? pls have a look at my code once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@Component` on the class .

```
@Component
Class Example{}
```

Comment: iam not using spring

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes your application must use any framework or cdi to use @inject

Comment: hey i had another issue, could  you please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367436/javax-inject-issue-getting-null